# Dynamically Change part of variable name?

Tags: reactjs

In React, is it possible to dynamically change part of a variable name based on state?

For example, I'm feeding several components information from a JSON file. Depending on the chosen gender (male or female), I want to send the 'atlas' from either the "male_clothes.js" or the "female_clothes.js".

JSX Code:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            current_gender: "male",
            current_pants: 0,
        }
<LimbSegment atlas={male_clothes[this.state.current_pants]['atlas']}/>
```

Comment: so you want to change `male_clothes` ? depending on what state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { current_pants, gender } = this.state // I assume gender is comming from the state
const clothes = gender === 'male' ? male_clothes : female_clothes
const atlas = clothes[current_pants].atlas
// Then:
<LimbSegment atlas={atlas}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood you correctly.
So if the `state.gender` is `male` it will use `male_clothes` otherwise `female_clothes`

```
<LimbSegment atlas={this.state.gender === 'male' ? 
male_clothes[this.state.current_pants]['atlas'] : 
female_clothes[this.state.current_pants]['atlas']}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short one:

```
<LimbSegment atlas={(this.state.someFlag ? male_clothes : female_clothes)[this.state.current_pants]['atlas']}/>
```

But it is better to use more verbose approach:

```
const clothes = this.state.someFlag ? male_clothes : female_clothes;
...
<LimbSegment atlas={clothes[this.state.current_pants]['atlas']}/>
```